# apt-daily.timer and apt-daily-upgrade.timer not triggering unattended-upgrades

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, systemd, unattended-upgrades

Using Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS.  I’m trying to get unattended-upgrades to run at a specific time. It is my understanding that as of Ubuntu 18.04 either the apt-daily.timer or the apt-daily-upgrade.timer trigger unattended-upgrades to run. However I’ve tried configuring an override file for both of them and neither seem to be triggering unattended-upgrades. I can’t for the life of me figure out why, or figure out what is triggering unattended-upgrades instead.

Comment: Why a specific time? Also, please add the full-width output of `systemctl list-timers` to your question showing that the override files did indeed set the timers for your desired time.